# Merge objects of an array in PHP using Eloquent

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, merge, eloquent

I have a collection of objects grabbed out of my DB using Laravel's Eloquent ORM ( I am not using Laravel just integrated Eloquent into my own Framework ). I used the [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-transform) method to iterate over the collection and `unserialize` one of the columns of each record, then [collapsed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-collapse) the collection to place all the unserialized objects in one array.

**Here is the logic:**

```
  $orders = Order::where('user', $user)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

  $orders->transform(function($order, $key) {

    $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);

    $items = $order->cart->items;

    return $items;
  });

  $collapsed = $orders->collapse();
```

**And Output:**

```
[
   {
      "qty": "2",
      "price": 200,
      "item": {
         "id": 1,
         "title": "Black Hoodie",
         "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/black-hoodie.jpg",
         "description": "Plain Black Hoodie.",
         "price": 100
      }
   },
   {
      "qty": "2",
      "price": 200,
      "item": {
         "id": 2,
         "title": "Green Hoodie",
         "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/green-hoodie.jpg",
         "description": "Plain Green Hoodie.",
         "price": 100
      }
   },
   {
      "qty": 1,
      "price": 100,
      "item": {
         "id": 2,
         "title": "Green Hoodie",
         "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/green-hoodie.jpg",
         "description": "Plain Green Hoodie.",
         "price": 100
      }
   },
   {
      "qty": 1,
      "price": 100,
      "item": {
         "id": 1,
         "title": "Black Hoodie",
         "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/black-hoodie.jpg",
         "description": "Plain Black Hoodie.",
         "price": 100
      }
   }
]
```

Now what I want to accomplish next is to combine all the identical objects in this array, ideally by their `"item":{"id"}` value, into one object - adding their `qty` and `price` properties together, leaving the `item` property the same.

**My Desired Output Would Be**

```
[
   {
      "qty": "3",
      "price": 300,
      "item": {
         "id": 1,
         "title": "Black Hoodie",
         "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/black-hoodie.jpg",
         "description": "Plain Black Hoodie.",
         "price": 100
      }
   },
   {
      "qty": "3",
      "price": 300,
      "item": {
         "id": 2,
         "title": "Green Hoodie",
         "img": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/green-hoodie.jpg",
         "description": "Plain Green Hoodie.",
         "price": 100
      }
   }
]
```

Eloquent has [TONS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#available-methods) of great methods available to work with collections, I'm just stuck on the right combination to efficiently achieve what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Fluent;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

// Mocking data to meet your requirements.
// Wrapping attributes inside fluent object,
// so we'll have almost same object like Eloquent model
$orders = new Collection([
    new Fluent([
        'qty' => 2,
        'price' => 200,
        'item' => new Fluent([
            'id' => 1,
            'price' => 100,
            'title' => 'Black Hoodie',
            'img' => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/black-hoodie.jpg',
            'description' => 'Plain Black Hoodie.',
        ])
    ]),
    new Fluent([
        'qty' => 2,
        'price' => 200,
        'item' => new Fluent([
            'id' => 2,
            'price' => 100,
            'title' => 'Green Hoodie',
            'img' => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/green-hoodie.jpg',
            'description' => 'Plain Green Hoodie.',
        ])
    ]),
    new Fluent([
        'qty' => 1,
        'price' => 100,
        'item' => new Fluent([
            'id' => 2,
            'price' => 100,
            'title' => 'Green Hoodie',
            'img' => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/green-hoodie.jpg',
            'description' => 'Plain Green Hoodie.',
        ])
    ]),
    new Fluent([
        'qty' => 1,
        'price' => 100,
        'item' => new Fluent([
            'id' => 1,
            'price' => 100,
            'title' => 'Black Hoodie',
            'img' => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/black-hoodie.jpg',
            'description' => 'Plain Black Hoodie.',
        ])
    ])
]);

// Here's something you might interested
$result = $orders->groupBy('item.id')
    ->map(function ($orders, $itemId) {
        return new Fluent([
            'qty' => $orders->sum('qty'), // calculating quantity
            'price' => $orders->sum('price'), // calculating total price
            'item' => $orders->first()->item // leave the item as it is
        ]);
    });

// You may evaluate the result here
dd($result);
```

### Update

More "raw" example:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

$orderOne = [
    'id' => 1,
    'price' => 100,
    'title' => 'Black Hoodie',
    'img' => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/black-hoodie.jpg',
    'description' => 'Plain Black Hoodie.',
];

$orderTwo = [
    'id' => 2,
    'price' => 100,
    'title' => 'Green Hoodie',
    'img' => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/green-hoodie.jpg',
    'description' => 'Plain Green Hoodie.',
];

$orders = new Collection([
    [
        'qty' => 2,
        'price' => 200,
        'item' => $orderOne
    ],
    [
        'qty' => 2,
        'price' => 200,
        'item' => $orderTwo
    ],
    [
        'qty' => 1,
        'price' => 100,
        'item' => $orderTwo
    ],
    [
        'qty' => 1,
        'price' => 100,
        'item' => $orderOne
    ]
]);

$result = $orders->groupBy('item.id')
    ->map(function ($orders, $itemId) {
        return [
            'qty' => $orders->sum('qty'),
            'price' => $orders->sum('price'),
            'item' => $orders->first()['item']
        ];
    });

dd($result);
```

Comment: ... and just like that your simplistic yet ingenious solution makes me feel brainless. At least I can say i was in the right direction haha! Gracias!